# Cannot access property from another class

Tags: php, symfony

Here's the code (didn't include namespaces, routing):

```
class OneController extends Controller{
    public $variable = "whatever";
    public function changeVariableAction(){
        $this->variable = "whenever";
        //  any code...
    $this->redirectToRoute("class_two_route_name");
    }

}

use AppBundle\Controller\OneController;
class Two{
    public function otherFunctionAction(){
    $reference = new One();
    return new Response($reference->variable);
    }
}
```

Why do I see "whatever" instead "whenever"? I know there is no line in the code executing `changeVariableAction()` but it is being executed when sb enters the route matching this action in `class One` ???

**EDIT:**

When I write the scheme outside SF3 I'm OK.

```
class One{
    public $variable = "whatever";
    public function changeVariable(){
        $this->variable = "whenever";
    }  
}
class Two{
    public function otherFunction(){
        $reference = new One();
        $reference->changeVariable();
        echo $reference->variable;
    }   
}
   $reference2 = new Two();
   $reference2->otherFunction();
```

Comment: You create a ***new instance*** of `One`. Any new instance will have `$variable` set to `whatever`. Your code says so.

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing "Whatever" instead of "Whenever" because of this line:

```
new One();
```

By calling "new One();" you are creating a new instance of the class "OneController" thus, it will set its default value "whatever" as the function "changeVariableAction" is not being called in your new instance $reference.

Comment: Yeah, that one I knew, but isn't the Action executed while entering route matching class One? If not then can I execute it in class Two?

Comment: It is executed upon route matching. The issue is that when you create a new instance in class Two, you are effectively working in a new environment of class One where the function has not been called yet. You could pass on the value you want to set to class Two, and use it further there. Or create a "update" function in class one you call from class Two and update it there.

Answer (score 0):

After research I can see that in SF (as it is a framework) we don't treat Action functions as typical functions (it's sth about http etc.) so we cannot execute them in another class. What's more, the whole code inside Action function doesn't influence the code outside the Action function. The only way to get new property value is to send them via argument in url (I don't think we want that) or send to db and retrieve it from database in another class.

Here's the proof:

```
class FirstController extends Controller{
    public $variable = "whatever";
    /**
     * @Route("/page")
     */
    public function firstAction(){
        $this->variable = "whenever";
        return $this->redirectToRoute("path");
    }
}

class SecondController{
    /**
     * @Route("/page/page2", name = "path")
     */
    public function secondAction(){
        $reference = new FirstController();
        $reference->firstAction();
        return new Response($reference->variable);    
    }
}
```

This code gives an error: Call to a member function get() on null.

When I delete line `$reference->firstAction();` there is no error and "whatever" shows up (so the original).